# Travis decrypting encrypted files with openssl fails

Tags: encryption, travis-ci

I have a project that requires some sensitive data. I have followed the steps specified at https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/encrypting-files/. However, some of the builds fail, and some others work just fine.
When a build succeeds I see this log:

```
Setting environment variables from repository settings
$ export encrypted_2c77c0ced414c_key=[secure]
$ export encrypted_2c77c0ced414c_iv=[secure]
$ export encrypted_c066d37aa1a1_key=[secure]
$ export encrypted_c066d37aa1a1_iv=[secure]
```

I don't see these environment variables when builds fail. I get this error instead:

```
The command "openssl aes-256-cbc -K $encrypted_2c77c0ced414c_key -iv $encrypted_c066d37aa1a1_key -in seeds.json.enc -out tests/data/seeds.json -d" failed and exited with 1 during .
```